# Assign last value within 1 minute intervals to rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```py
    time                    val

    2019-10-01 04:00:00.000 568830.000
    2019-10-01 17:47:29.794 37612.000
    2019-10-01 19:41:03.697 37.000
    2019-10-01 19:41:03.698 37612.000
    2019-10-02 00:16:07.224 376.000
    2019-10-02 00:16:07.225 37612.000
    2019-10-02 01:19:05.135 3761.000
    2019-10-02 01:19:05.136 37612.000
    2019-10-02 08:26:27.623 36612.000
    2019-10-02 08:26:27.624 36493.000
    2019-10-03 07:08:54.455 364.000
    2019-10-03 07:08:54.456 36493.000
```

I want to create a new column that contains the **last** value within X minutes intervals e.g. 1 minute of column `val`.

Expected output:

```py
    time                    val        result

    2019-10-01 04:00:00.000 568830.000 568830.000
    2019-10-01 17:47:29.794 37612.000  37612.000
    2019-10-01 19:41:03.697 37.000     37612.000
    2019-10-01 19:41:03.698 37612.000  37612.000
    2019-10-02 00:16:07.224 376.000    37612.000
    2019-10-02 00:16:07.225 37612.000  37612.000
    2019-10-02 01:19:05.135 3761.000   37612.000
    2019-10-02 01:19:05.136 37612.000  37612.000
    2019-10-02 08:26:27.623 36612.000  36493.000 
    2019-10-02 08:26:27.624 36493.000  36493.000
    2019-10-03 07:08:54.455 364.000    36493.000
    2019-10-03 07:08:54.456 36493.000  36493.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for `DatetimeIndex` [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) and `last`:

```
df['result'] = df.resample('T')['val'].transform('last')
print (df)
                              val    result
time                                       
2019-10-01 04:00:00.000  568830.0  568830.0
2019-10-01 17:47:29.794   37612.0   37612.0
2019-10-01 19:41:03.697      37.0   37612.0
2019-10-01 19:41:03.698   37612.0   37612.0
2019-10-02 00:16:07.224     376.0   37612.0
2019-10-02 00:16:07.225   37612.0   37612.0
2019-10-02 01:19:05.135    3761.0   37612.0
2019-10-02 01:19:05.136   37612.0   37612.0
2019-10-02 08:26:27.623   36612.0   36493.0
2019-10-02 08:26:27.624   36493.0   36493.0
2019-10-03 07:08:54.455     364.0   36493.0
2019-10-03 07:08:54.456   36493.0   36493.0
```

And for column `time` add parameter `on`:

```
df['result'] = df.resample('T', on='time')['val'].transform('last')
print (df)
                      time       val    result
0  2019-10-01 04:00:00.000  568830.0  568830.0
1  2019-10-01 17:47:29.794   37612.0   37612.0
2  2019-10-01 19:41:03.697      37.0   37612.0
3  2019-10-01 19:41:03.698   37612.0   37612.0
4  2019-10-02 00:16:07.224     376.0   37612.0
5  2019-10-02 00:16:07.225   37612.0   37612.0
6  2019-10-02 01:19:05.135    3761.0   37612.0
7  2019-10-02 01:19:05.136   37612.0   37612.0
8  2019-10-02 08:26:27.623   36612.0   36493.0
9  2019-10-02 08:26:27.624   36493.0   36493.0
10 2019-10-03 07:08:54.455     364.0   36493.0
11 2019-10-03 07:08:54.456   36493.0   36493.0
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. But how do I specify the time window that I want to get the last value from? In my example, I wanted a 1 minute window, but it is not specified anywhere in the code provided as solution.

Comment: @pmanresa93 - It is `T`, it means `1Min`, you can change it by table in [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that you time column is of type string. You can use the following line which will perform the group by.

```
df.groupby(df.time.map(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t).minute)).val.last()
```

But to then make a new column that contains these values you can use `transform` which would look like the following

```
df['result'] = df.groupby(df.time.map(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t).minute)).val.transform('last')
```

**Note** that I am assuming here that you want to group by the minute part of the timestamp.